# Get totals or sum source medium filter, Google Analytics API

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-api

```
Post request https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet

    {
  "reportRequests":[
  
  {
    "viewId":"XXXXXX",
    "dateRanges":[
    {
      "startDate":"2021-07-01",
      "endDate":"2021-07-31"
    }, 
    {
      "startDate":"2020-07-01",
      "endDate":"2020-07-31"
    }],
    "metrics":[
    {
      "expression":"ga:sessions"
    }],
    "dimensions": [
    {
      "name":"ga:sourceMedium"
    }],
      "dimensionFilterClauses": [
                {"filters": [
                    {"dimensionName": "ga:sourceMedium",
                        "operator": "EXACT",
                        "expressions": ["google / cpc"]},
                    {"dimensionName": "ga:sourceMedium",
                        "operator": "EXACT",
                        "expressions": ["facebook / cpc"]},
                 ]}
            ]
  }]
}
```

Want response with total / finished summed values for ga:sourceMedium "google / cpc" and "facebook / cpc". With this body i get a response with values for each ga:sourceMedium separated. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Analytics Reporting API returns that data that it has. so you are requesting ga:sourceMedium This returns `Combined values of ga:source and ga:medium`.

You are also requesting ga:sessions which will return `The total number of sessions.`

So the api will return the total sessions fore ach of the source and medium combination.

If you want to sum them you will need to do that locally the api is not going to do that for you.

Comment: OK, thanks. So its not possible to set google / cpc+facebook / cpc?

Comment: No you cant change the data in Google analytics once it has been recorded.